# ExtJS GroupingView get active or clicked group or add a link to group header

Tags: extjs4

Hard to make a right title for the question but here i go.

What i am trying to do:
Using ExtJS GroupingView to group results in the table. I need to be able to run a function for active/selected group or add a link to the group header.

The function will do an ajax request to initiate an update on backend (not for table update) - with one parameter from that group.

The group essentially shows history/log ( with a download link to  old file in each row as well - so it has to be rows to access each one through click event).

It worked fine if i simply looked for active/selected row ( no multiselect) - but that expects user to select a row after expanding the category - it should allow to use the download button ( global, on top of the table)  and get the current "active" or last clicked group and get a value from it (unique id).
OR a download link/button/icon in the header.

i do not know the number of rows, groups or data there will be.

All in initComponent.

Problems:

No click/last select event or value available to capture later.
Cannot use onclick in the groupRenderer - i cannot access the function (undefined - its outside the init).

Question:
How can i run a function for each group. In ether  groupRenderer formatted group header or through a global button to detect current clicked group header.

restrictions:
Cannot use 3rd party modules/libraries or call external page (href) - it has to run and work within that one page/js script.

Group column is formatted throug groupRenderer - can get values from store with .get()  and pass the right value to the store from php.
I simply cannto find a way to pass it on to the right function for the selected column or do it in the column header directly by calling the function on click for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up using  the 'groupclick' event.

It passes along the field and value used to sort by which i could use to find the data from store.

```
this.store.data.items.map(function(val){}
```